# Confirmation for inappropriate choice of macro definition name in C

Tags: c, misra, cppcheck

Is there a relable reference that can confirm that using a name of a number as macro (in C) is inappropriate ?

Consider the follwing example:

```
#define ZERO (0)
#define ONE (1)
#define TWO (2)
#define THREE (3)
#define FOUR (4)
// ... etc
```

Comment: I wouldn't say _"inappropriate"_ but perhaps pointless. `FOUR` doesn't tell the reader of the code more than what `4` does, so why make a macro out of it?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing, but anyway IMO there is no added value. If you see `1` then you obviously know that it is `1`. If you see `ONE` it could potentially be something else than `1`. BTW the parentheses around the digits are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Reserved names (beginning with `__` or `_[A-Z]`) are sort of "inappropriate". Then, for macros put in a public header, you'll probably want to prefix them with your lib's name to avoid collisions.

Comment: What is the purpose of macros like that? While it's good to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), using `TWO` or `2` doesn't really change anything. And for something like that, perhaps an `enum` would have been better? But it still needs to add something to the code, just an enumeration of numbers doesn't add anything.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with [tag:misra], is there any particular paragraph in there that you have in mind in the context of the question?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is part of my question. If there is such, then I can use it as relaible reference.

Comment: @IvanDimitrov Sure, if following the misra rules is a requirement where you are working.   I wouldn't advocate following misra blindly in "normal" projects though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, clarifying as requested. -- If MISRA is part of your question, please add which rule(s) you have in mind.

Comment: Yes.  ISO TR/13497, EN50138, IEC6126, et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about these very macros specifically... then the answer is to use neither `1` nor `ONE`. As usual, common sense will get you very far: use a named constant which states a *meaningful* name communicating to the reader what that constant is to be used for. Not what number it contains.

If you are moving and pack your shoes in a cardboard box, you would write "shoes" on the box right? Not "ten" because there are ten shoes in the box.

That is:

```c
// GOOD
#define SIZE 5
size_t x = SIZE;

// BAD
size_t x = 5; // size

// BAD
#define FIVE 5
size_t x = FIVE; // size
```

The first bad example is bad because there's no explanation where that number came from - the programmer seems to just have pulled it out of a hat. These are called "magic numbers" and are widely recognized as bad practice.

The comments in both bad examples became necessary just because the code isn't self-documenting. We wouldn't have needed that comment if a macro with a sensible name was used

---

As far as MISRA is concerned, the relevant rule is MISRA C:2012 20.7 telling you to always wrap function-like macros inside parenthesis. Since this is already fundamental good practice in C, it should come as no surprise to C programmers.

But these are not function-like macros but macro constants. We can then note that the same MISRA rule also mentions this in the rationale:

> If a macro paramete ris not being used as an expression then the parenthesis are not necessary because no operators are involved

This also makes perfect sense, because we sometimes want to expand macros and perhaps use them together with `#` or `##` operators, which will not be possible if there's a parenthesis there. So drop the extra parenthesis, it is just harmful clutter.

---

Notably, for MISRA compliance, integer constants that are used in a context where they should be unsigned must be written as `5u` or `5U`.

Answer (score 2):

As the question has a MISRA tag, I can answer that part:

MISRA C (or C++ for that matter) makes no recommendations about naming conventions of functions, objects or macros - other than Rules 21.1 & 21.2 which prohibit use of reserved identifiers, and Directive 4.5 which requires they should be typographically distinct.

However, MISRA Compliance also requires certain supporting processes - one of which is a style guide (which it is assumed includes local details of naming conventions).

As a code reviewer, I would offer short shrift to any programmer who offered any of the items in the original post... I don't need MISRA or any other guidance to tell me that such definitions add no value - that is covered by *C programming 101*

Comment: +1.  Way too often I've seen "magic numbers" interpreted effectively as "no bare numbers".  I swear a few of those knuckleheads would demand the quadratic formula be written as `double root1 = ( -b + sqrt( b * b - FOUR * a * c ) ) / ( TWO * a );`  Yeah, just no.  That's **stupid**.